# Fuzzy Search Within Text Document

Tags: text, fuzzy-search

Say I have a long document, and I have some keywords that I wish to determine the relevance. For example, say I have the document

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

And the keywords, `ipsum` and `amet`. How can I test whether they are in the document, but allow spelling mistakes in the document. For example,

```
Loremm ipsum dolor sit ammet.
```

I'm more looking for information about what this is called, or even better, a JS module.

Comment: Are you looking for [Approximate string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching)?

Comment: You could use the Levenshtein distance, but you'd have to test every single word (although most words will return a distance of close to your target word+source word length, i.e., "total replacement").